# Getting Recent Post Time in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to dynamically show the **Last Posted Date and time on Header** in Wordpress. Please help me with the code that I can get the last posted date and time from the WP database and fetch it on my Header.php or Somewhere else (HTML). Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this code to get last post date and time in header.php

```
<?php echo get_lastpostdate(); ?>
```

Here is the function reference https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_lastpostdate

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_get_recent_posts()` to get the latest post:

```
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( array( 'numberposts' => '1' ) );
echo $recent_posts[0]['post_date'];
```